# Adding P1M (one month) to a DateInterval type adds two months

Tags: php, date

> ***Important note:*** My question is specifically about **`DateInterval`**. I am **NOT** interested in **`DateTime::modify()`** that is proposed in some answers. This is therefore not a duplicate.

I try to add a `DateInterval` of `P1M` (one month) to a `DateTime` object using a `DateInterval` object. Unfortunately, this seems to result in two months being added.

This code (please mind the echoes):

```
<?php
    $date = date('m-Y');

    echo $date . '<br />';

    $date_subonemonth = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $date);
    $date_addonemonth = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $date); 

    echo $date_subonemonth->format('m-Y') . '<br />';
    echo $date_addonemonth->format('m-Y') . '<br />';

    $one_month = new DateInterval('P1M');

    $date_subonemonth = $date_subonemonth->sub($one_month)->format('m-Y');
    $date_addonemonth = $date_addonemonth->add($one_month)->format('m-Y');

    echo $date_subonemonth . '<br />';
    echo $date_addonemonth . '<br />';      

?>
```

Outputs the following:

```
01-2020
01-2020
01-2020
12-2019
03-2020
```

The last echo should output `02-2020` instead, it output `1-2020` when I added `$one_month` to it.

Why does this happen? And how can I solve this using `DateInterval`?

Comment: The question has been edited to explain it does not relate to DateTime::modify (which has answers) but specifically to DateInterval, please reopen.

Comment: It's the same issue. When you're creating a date without specifying the day, it uses the current day, which today is 31. There is no February 31st, so adding a month moves it to March 2nd (this year, it's usually March 3rd, I think). The way to fix it is to modify the date you create to be the first of the month, and then adding months will work as expected.

Comment: Ok, understood, thank you.